# Find the Points of Interest of a certain city

Tags: sql-server, database, foursquare, google-places-api

what I try to do, and have found a naive solution so far, is to get all the Points Of Interest of a certain city using APIs like Foursquare API and Google Places and insert them into an SQL server instance.
My naive solution was to get the latitude and longitude of certain cities from here
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

and use the functions provided by these APIs applying the radius parameter.
Because of the fact that both APIs will return up to a maximum number of Points Of Interest (50 for example in foursquare), what I do is to use a small radius (~40m) and make repeated requests to the APIs using closely latitude-longitude pairs.
My problem is that I have to manually find the borders of a city so that not to exceed them.
Is there any other way to get the "borders" of a city, for example a database that has latitude-longitude polygons for cities?

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867833/3623027) of mine

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way of doing this, but you should check out this related question. It discusses how to get city borders:

[How can I get the city borders for a country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499511/how-can-i-get-the-city-borders-for-a-country)